# User is not associated with trusted connection

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a installed 2005 sqlexpress as well as express manager studio.
I added a login under Logins, associated user with my database and gave it db_owner role under User mapping.

Now I right click on the server, under properties change from windows authentication to sql server authentication, enter login and password, click test and I get error:

Login failed for user... User is not associated.. Error: 18452.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked more into that Mixed Mode suggested by CodeByMoonlight, and found that I had to change the registry entry since MIXED MODE WAS NOT ENABLED, even though I had windows and sql authetntication as login methods in properties tab. To change to mixed mode run regedit from command line and change this entry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQLServer

LoginMode =2

If you need to have sysadmin access, and if you don't know 'sa' password you can add new one like this:

SQLCMD -S.\SQLEXPRESS -E

sp_addLogin ‘username’, ‘pass’
GO
sp_addsrvrolemember ‘username’, ’sysadmin’
GO

Answer (score 0):

Did you also change the Server to use Mixed Mode rather than just Windows Authentication? If so, you need to restart the server for this to take effect.

Comment: That's the thing, I read about this mixed mode, but I don't have it when I right click on the server>properties. I just have Sql and windows authetntication, no mixed mode.

Comment: Sorry, confusing term. Mixed Mode just means both authentication types are available, and you've done this.

Comment: Next question : have you set the Default database of your new login to one it has access to?

Comment: Yes I did. I did that under Logins>Default Database